# Eclipse displays red values for a Java byte array when debugging

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, debugging, rxtx

I am currently working on a software that makes a serial communication with a hand-made simulator using the RXTX library. To test the limits of my software, I set distinct COM parameters between my 2 programs ; the main software send messages with a baud rate of 9600 and the simulator receives with a baud rate of 19200.

When I try to send the following array: `"GET IN_NUM_TRAIN".getBytes()` (16 bytes), my simulator receives a byte array containing 27 elements and throws:

> INFOS: Traitement du message : ~�``�8���f���f�
>
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 26

When I try debugging my code, the received byte array looks like this:

[image: Byte array displayed by Eclipse]

I don't understand why the 8 first values are displayed in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 8 **values** are displayed **in red** to indicate that they have **changed**.

See [Eclipse Help - *Java development user guide > Reference > Preferences > Debug Preferences*](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-run_debug.htm):

> **Changed value color**
>
> This option allows you to change the color of a changed value in the
>   variables view, expressions view, memory view, anywhere running
>   program variables are rendered
>
> Default: **Red**

Comment: It raises other problems for me because I haven't made changes after defining each value for my array... I'll analyze this, thank you very much :)